# How can I update various input fields with one button?

Tags: php, e-commerce

Apologies if I don't ask my question clear enough or the wording is ambiguous in the question.

I am currently coding a shopping cart for an e-commerce website and I have been using tutorials to help get me to my current stage but now I am stuck.

The following is the specific line which allows customers to change the quantity and the 'change' button that comes up next to it.

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
<input name="quantity" type="text"  class="form-element text-element form-element-small" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
<input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
<input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
</form>
```

The above code is part of $cartOutput - which is then echo'd in the the DIV later on.

The following is the button I tried to create to update all quantities but right now all it does is refresh the page.

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
<input class="btn sub-btn" name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="Update">Update Cart</input>
<input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
</form>
```

Literally, any help on this would be great!

Edit:

Here is the complete php block that the first piece of code came from:

```
<?php 

$cartOutput = "";
$minicartOutput = "";
$cartTotal = "";
$pp_checkout_btn = '';
$product_id_array = '';
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
    $minicartOutput = "<p>You have no items in your cart</p>";
} else {
    // Start PayPal Checkout Button
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="xxxxxxxxx" value="xxxxxxxxxx">';
    // Start the For Each loop
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $shade = $row["shade"];
            $details = $row["details"];
        }
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
        $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
        // Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly
        $x = $i + 1;
        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $x . '" value="' . $product_name . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $x . '" value="' . $price . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $x . '" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
        // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $minicartOutput .= '<div class="form shopping-cart-form">

                                                        <form id="update_cart_form" method="post" action="/cart.php"  >



                                <ul class="listing cart-ul quick-cart-ul">
                                                            <li class="listing-li cart-li quick-cart-li first-li" data-quantity="1" data-id="149"> 
                                    <div class="box cart-item-box"> 
                                        <fieldset class="form-data-group">
                                            <legend class="form-legend">' . $product_name . '</legend>
                                            <dl class="meta-listing cart-item-dl">
                                                <dt class="meta-listing-dt cart-item-dt">Quantity</dt>
                                                <dd class="meta-listing-dd cart-item-dd">' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</dd>
                                                <dt class="meta-listing-dt cart-item-dt quick-cart-item-dt-price hide-me"><!--Price--></dt>
                                                <dd class="meta-listing-dd cart-item-dd quick-cart-item-dd-price">' . $pricetotal . '</dd>
                                            </dl>
                                            <div class="related cart-item-related">
                                                <div class="media img-media cart-item-img-media">
                                                    <figure>

                                                        <img width="56" height="56" src="../uploads/inventory/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" />                                                      
                                                                                                            </figure>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </li>


                                                        </ul>
                                                        </form>';
        $cartOutput .= '<div class="form shopping-cart-form">
                                <form id="update_cart_form" method="post" action="/cart.php"  >


                            <ul class="listing cart-ul">
                                                            <li class="listing-li cart-li first-li">
                                    <div class="box cart-item-box"> 
                                        <fieldset class="form-data-group">
                                            <legend class="form-legend">' . $product_name . '</legend>
                                            <dl class="meta-listing cart-item-dl cart-item-dl-price">
                                                <dt class="meta-listing-dt cart-item-dt">Price</dt>
                                                <dd class="meta-listing-dd cart-item-dd cart-item-dd-price">' . $pricetotal . '</dd>
                                            </dl>
                                            <dl class="meta-listing cart-item-dl">
                                                <dt class="meta-listing-dt cart-item-dt">Shade</dt>
                                                <dd class="meta-listing-dd cart-item-dd">' . $shade . '</dd>
                                                <dt class="meta-listing-dt cart-item-dt">Quantity</dt>
                                                <dd class="meta-listing-dd cart-item-dd">
                                                     <form action="cart.php" method="post">
                                                        <input name="quantity" type="text"  class="form-element text-element form-element-small" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" /><input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" /><input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" /></form> 
                                                </dd>
                                            </dl>
                                                <form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" class="form-label remove-from-cart-form-label delete-from-cart" type="submit" value="Remove From Cart" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form>
                                            <div class="related cart-item-related">
                                                <div class="media img-media cart-item-img-media">
                                                    <figure>

                                                           <img width="56" height="56" src="../uploads/inventory/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" />

                                                                                                            </figure>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </li>                               
                                                            </ul>

                                </form>';
        $i++; 
    }
```

?>

(There is a bit more but that has to do with Paypal Check out)

This should be the final edit... This is the php block that deals with adjusting quantities.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
?>
```

Comment: do you want input fields to be updated with the same value on all of them ?

Comment: Hey @GGio, I want the separate input fields to update individually. So for instance, if there are three products, and the user changes Product A to 5, B to 7 and C to 2, I would want all values to update at the click of the 'Update Cart' button (hope that makes sense)

Comment: Where's the PHP code?

Comment: Hi @EM-Creations i didn't know whether the whole php block was relevant or not? If you think it is I can add it to the original post?

Comment: @JioFreed Yes it is relevant, please edit your opening post. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant, but you are not getting any $_POST data?

Comment: @JelledeFries indeed I am.. yet another bit I missed out! Apologies

Comment: anybody got any ideas??

Comment: I think what @JelledeFries meant was: can you give us a dump of $_POST? Thanks :) And I for my part don't understand: do you want to update several items with an several input fields that all have the same name?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer well, yeah, though now it seems like thats a bad idea!

Comment: @JioFreed use name="something[]" or name="item_[ID]" (replace [ID] obviously), and can you then provide a dump of $_POST?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer definitely a newbie question, but how do I create a POST dump?

Comment: By "dump" I refer to the PHP-function var_dump(), i.e. var_dump($_POST), see manual here http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php

Comment: @simonthesorcerer I hope this is the right thing. I adjusted the quantity of one item and this is what returned: array(3) {
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["adjustBtn6"]=>
  string(6) "change"
  ["item_to_adjust"]=>
  string(1) "6"
}

I changed the quantity to 4, and the item_id of the product is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating multiple items does not depend on the button, but on the input-fields that keep the values. You should use one field of a type for each item, i.e. if you need the fields "item_to_adjust" and "quantity", each item should have these fields.
Looking at your form, I think this will do:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
<?php
// loop through your items/item-ids/whatever you use
foreach($cart_items as $item) {
    $item_id = $item['id']
    echo '
    <input name="quantity[]" type="text"  class="form-element text-element form-element-small" value="' . $item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
    <input name="item_to_adjust[]" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
} ?>
<input name="adjustBtn" type="submit" value="change" />
</form>
```

You will get:

```
<?php
    $_POST['item_to_adjust'] = array([0] => 127, [1] => 6, [...]); // item-ids
    $_POST['quantity'] = array([0] => 1, [1] => 15, [...]); // quantities
```

Put item-ids to quantites, and you have all items and can adjust the quantities with your code:

```
<?php
// $cart_items_ne will be: array('127' => 1, '6' => 15, [...]);
$cart_items_new = array_combine($_POST['item_to_adjust'],$_POST['quantity']);

// update items
foreach($cart_items_new as $item_id => $quantity) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Was that the answer you searched for?

Comment: hey @simonthesorcerer, this looks like it should work - thank you! I am a bit confused though as to where would I be putting the second and third php blocks?

Comment: Sorry, I am very late... The 2nd and 3rd blocks go where you catch your data, in the example it's the cart.php-file