# Placing buttons outside html forms

Tags: php, html, forms, button

I've been having trouble getting all my forms to execute the php properly on submits.

I basically have a cart which is rendering every item being added to the cart

```
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= "<td>" . $product_name . "</td>";
        $cartOutput .= "<td>$" . $price . "</td>";
        $cartOutput .= "<td>" . $case_weight . "</td>";
        $cartOutput .= "<td><form action='shop.php' method='post'>
        <input class='quantity' name='quantity[]' type='text' value='" . $each_item['quantity'] . "' size='1' maxlength='2'/>
        <input name='item_to_adjust[]' type='hidden' value='" . $item_id . "'</form></td>";
        $cartOutput .= "<td>$" . $priceTotal . "</td>";
        $cartOutput .= "<td><form action='retail_shop.php' method='post'><input name='deleteButton' type='image' value='' src='images/shop-x.gif' /><input name='index_to_remove' type='hidden' value='" . $i . "'/></form></td>";
        $cartOutput .= "</tr>";
```

I had a button elsewhere that would post to shop and execute a php to update inputs like quantity. It didn't work because it's not able to "access" the form. I looked at this and answer #2 with html 5
[Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)

It seems like I can use `form="xx"` on the button to access it. I have multiple forms being generated and they don't have ID's right now, but if I added ID's, they would all need to be unique.. It also says I can't do this in IE.

Is this the right way to go about it? Will I be able to access the form from anywhere (even outside the table) as long as it references the id?

Comment: Why are you not placing the button inside the form? You could also use JavaScript?

Comment: If I place it in cart output then i'll end up with a button for each cell for each item. I only want one button. So I have to put it outside the cartOutput. Is there a way without mucking with JS?

Comment: Why don't you place the form tag outside too?

Comment: So right now you are creating a form for every item in the shopping cart?  How would a single button be able to submit all of these forms unless you had a button for each form?  I think what @putvande is getting at is that you should place the form around all of the items, add a unique id to each item input, and submit all the data when the submit button is pressed.

Comment: I basically had this going on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683047/how-can-i-update-various-input-fields-with-one-button I had individual change buttons and wanted to update input quantities all in one go. I had this..
`<tbody>
    <?php  echo $cartOutput; ?>
</tbody>`
if there are rows and td cells inbetween, will that interfer with the function of  the form?